# How to Create Different Conda Environments for Different Branches of a Git Repository?

Tags: python, git, anaconda

I am currently working on a project in a Git repository that has several different branches. I would like to set up two different conda environments, each using the code from a different branch of this one repository.

I would like each of these environments to be completely independent because I run my project on a compute cluster and would like to queue multiple jobs running on different branches of the repository simultaneously.

More specifically, my repository is organized like

```
my-repo/
    master
    issue-fix
    additional-feature
```

and I would like to create one conda environment called something like `env1` that uses the code in `issue-fix` along with some other packages. Then, I would like to create another environment called `env2` that uses code in `additional-feature` along with those same other packages.

With the code in branch `issue-fix` checked-out, I've tried running the following to create both environments:

```
conda create -n env1
source activate env1
conda install <my other packages>
pip install -e git+file:///path/to/repo@issue-fix#egg=repo-0.1
source deactivate
conda create -n env2
source activate env2
conda install <my other packages>
pip install -e git+file:///path/to/repo@additional-feature#egg=repo-0.1
```

However, in environment `env2`, the code in branch `additional-feature` was inaccessible. How should I go about setting up these two environments?

Comment: Did `conda install <my other packages`> in the second environment include `pip`? What is the output of `which pip` with the environments activated?

Comment: @darthbith I don't install `pip` explicitly with the other packages. However those other packages depend on pip so it ends up getting installed with the first of my other packages. In `env1`, `which pip` returns `~/.conda/envs/env1/bin/pip`. In `env2`, `which pip` returns `~/.conda/envs/env2/bin/pip`.

Comment: does your code have packages in itself? what is the intent of `pip install -e git+file:///path/to/repo@additional-feature`? you normally git clone and checkout to branch to switch to it, why do you resort to pip for that? is that because you want isolation?

Comment: @EPo Yes, the repository is a package itself. To clarify, I'm working on this project in a team, and I am just testing functionality in the `issue-fix` branch, but I am developing new features myself in the `additional-feature` branch. I hope to have separate environments for each branch so each can be tested and edited independently.

Comment: What prevents you from just activating a different environment and switching to a branch? This is the first snd easiest thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @EPo I see what you mean, but I'm running both branches in parallel and I worry that I'll have a script that tries to execute `issue-fix`, then shortly thereafter another script will try to checkout and run `additional-feature`, modifying the directory that is already executing. I imagine that would create some kind of error. But to your point if switching environments and checking out the right branch would allow parallel execution without interference then that is definitely easiest.

Comment: By saying in parallel do you mean you have two python processes that execute two branches? That is a bit unusual, what task domain is it? I can see a problem invoking the processes as you can activate just one environment at a time, so you will need a runner/launcher script.

Comment: @EPo By in parallel I mean I would like two different nodes on a compute cluster to be running different branches simultaneously. Each node is its own system (managed by Slurm Workload Manager) but all nodes access data from the same file system as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very interesting problem which I am running into now. I have a repo with two branches in very active development and I need to switch back and forth quite often. The branches have different compiled code (Fortran & C) versions which means that every time I `git checkout <branch>` I need to recompile code. Not optimal to say the least.

I would like to have two conda environments, with a different branch installed in each env. I would like to have two python kernels running, one started from each conda env and be able to test (run code) in both without doing switching branches (only the window I work in).

What I ended up doing is cloning the repo twice under separate testing directories, both separate from the main repo's main dev dir, checking out different branches in each directory and installing each in a separate conda environment.

As long as I don't touch the master branch in each of those testing directories, I will be able to push upstream and merge when I am ready.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have recently been trying to do the same thing, and found that you can specify the directory for a repo by adding `--src <target-repo-directory>` to the pip install command. Using different target directories will then allow you to install different branches in different conda virtual environments (which you can confirm with `pip list`).

For the example above, you would want:

```
mkdir /path/to/issue-fix-branch
mkdir /path/to/additional-feature-branch
conda create -n env1
source activate env1
conda install <my other packages>
pip install --src /path/to/issue-fix-branch -e git+file:///path/to/repo@issue-fix#egg=repo-0.1
source deactivate
conda create -n env2
source activate env2
conda install <my other packages>
pip install --src /path/to/additional-feature-branch -e git+file:///path/to/repo@additional-feature#egg=repo-0.1
```